# Sup of $p$-norms of positions of martingale and $p$-norm of its closure

Tags: probability-theory, normed-spaces, martingales

Let $(\Omega, (\mathcal{F}_t), P)$ be a filtered probability space.

Let $1\leq p\leq \infty$ and $M$ be a $p$-integrable $(\mathcal{F}_t)$-martingale closed by $M_\infty$. What do we need from $(\mathcal{F}_t)$, $p$, and $M_\infty$ (e.g. right-continuity of filtration, $p<\infty$, $p$-integrability of $M_\infty$) in order to have
$$
\sup_{0\leq t<\infty}\Vert M_t\Vert_p = \Vert M_\infty\Vert_p?
$$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Nothing more  is needed. Assume for the moment that $M_\infty\in L^p$. $M$ admits a right continuous modification, call it $X$. The process $X$ is a martingale with respect to $(\mathcal F_{t+})$. Being a modification of $M$, $X$ is also closed by $M_\infty$, and because $X$ is right continuous, you have $\lim_{t\to\infty} X_t=M_\infty$ a.s. and in $L^p$. Because $X$ is a modification of $M$:
$$
\sup_{0\le t<\infty}\|M_t\|_p=\sup_{0\le t<\infty}\|X_t\|_p.
$$
Also, $t\mapsto \|X_t\|_p$ increases because $|X_t|^p$ is a submartingale. It follows that $$
\sup_{0\le t<\infty}\|M_t\|_p=\sup_{0\le t<\infty}\|X_t\|_p=\lim_{t\to\infty}\|X_t\|_p =\|M_\infty\|_p.
$$

The 1-integrability of $M_\infty$ is implicit in "$M$ is closed by $M_\infty$". For $p>1$,  the $p$-integrability is not needed. Indeed, by Fatou and the previously noted monotonicity, $\|M_\infty\|_p\le\sup_{0\le t<\infty}\|M_t\|_p$. And if this last inequality is strict, then $M_\infty$ is $p$-integrable.

Comment: Thanks! So we only need $M$ to be a.s. convergent to $M_\infty$? Why is that exactly if $M_\infty$ isn't $p$-integrable or $p=1$?

Comment: I interpreted "$M$ [...] closed by $M_\infty$" to mean that $M_t=\Bbb E[M_\infty\mid\mathcal F_t]$, $t\ge 0$. Implicit in this is that $M_\infty\in L^1$.  We then know that $M_t$ converges a.s. and in $L^1$ to $M_\infty$.I interpreted "

Comment: Why do we know that $M_t$ converges a.s. to $M_\infty$? I know that is the case if the time-sup $\sup_t M_t$ is integrable, but I didn't assume that and I don't see how closedness implies $M_t$ to have an integrable time-sup either

Comment: This is Lévy's theorem. The a.s. convergence (to some $L^1$ r.v., call it $Z$) needs only that $\sup_t\Bbb E[|M_t|]$ be finite. The a.s. limit closes the martingale, in the sense that $M_t=\Bbb E[Z|\mathcal F_t]$ for all $t$, if and only if $(M_t)$ is uniformly integrable. This is a weaker condition than $\sup_t|M_t|\in L^1$.